# Question to do with ETF price changes during the day

Tags: etf, mutual-funds, index-fund, price, market-indexes

In my learnings I was told the nav price of an etf is calculated at the end of the trading day,So the next day trading resumes at that price but then fluctuates due to supply and demand for the etf rather than the change in the price of the underlying assets.The process of creation and redemption stop prices from deviating from nav however if this is the case surely this must also happens at one time during the day(ie the creation and redemption process) because the NAV is only calculated once .Otherwise the etf price will stay the same the whole trading day due to the constant creation and redemption process and the only time the etf price properly changes is when the nav is recalculated at the end of the day for a different price for the new day tomorrow.

Can someone give me some advice ? sorry if post doesnt make sense, i may describe myself as being at an intermediate level .

Answer (score 4):

> In my learnings I was told the nav price of an etf is calculated at the end of the trading day. So the next day trading resumes at that price but then fluctuates due to supply and demand for the etf rather than the change in the price of the underlying assets.

Not true - the NAV and price (which is just the total NAV divided by the number of outstanding units) of a ***mutual fund*** is calculated at the end of the day, because units of a mutual fund are only bought and sold at the end of the trading day at that price. IF you put in an order to buy units of a mutual fund, that order is filled at the end of the day, and you don't know exactly the price at which the order will be fulfilled until the end of the day.

The NAV and price of an ETF (Exchange-Traded [mutual] Fund) changes as the value of its constituents changes, and units of the ETF can be traded throughout the day at the fair price.  Yes, supply and demand can cause the price of the ETF to become slightly detached from the value of its constituents, but there are authorized participants who use arbitrage to keep the price roughly in line with the intrinsic value.

I think the rest of your questions stem from that faulty assumption.